# Redirect URL to a IP address

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, ip

I need to redirect a url www.website.com/page to a Ip address 192.000.00.000:1234

Do i have to do this through the Cpanel or is there a way to do it in the .htaccess

Cant find anything that describes how to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Had to use

```
Redirect 301 /page.php http://192.000.00.000:1234
```

For it to work. Was on a wordpress site.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried:

```
Redirect 301 / 192.000.00.000:1234
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Enable .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/page\.php$ http://192.000.00.000:1234
```

Comment: It didn't work because of wrong information in your question. You wrote: `I need to redirect a url www.website.com/page to a Ip address 192.000.00.000:1234` no mention of `page.php`

Comment: the website.com/page wouldnt work as that is how its permalinks are displayed in wordpress. so i added the .php and it worked.

Comment: Good that you got it working but just fyi in future try to put as much as info as possible in your question and tag your question properly like wordpress, php etc.